# npm module for clarifai not found when I start the node server

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, clarifai

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'clarifai'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shiva/seefood-backend/app.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

I get the above message in terminal when I do `node app.js`. I have installed Clarifai npm package as mentioned on https://developer.clarifai.com/quick-start/ with `npm install clarifai` but it still gives me this error. Do I need to install the package globally?
Also this is my `app.js` :

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var Clarifai = require('clarifai')
var secrets = require('./secrets')
var keys = secrets.clarifaiConfig()

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var ClarifaiInstance = new Clarifai.App(
  keys.access_key,
  keys.secret_key
)

var store

var foodModel = 'bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7'
var fnol = function getPredictionAsJSON(imageURL) {
  ClarifaiInstance.models.predict(foodModel, imageURL).then(
    function(response) {
      store = response.outputs[0].data
      console.log(store + ' from inside the fn');
    },
    function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
  return store
}

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Recognize app listening on port 8000!')

  app.post('/classify', function(req, res) {
    var clarifaiData
    var imageURL = req.body.imageURL
      clarifaiData = fnol(imageURL)
      // console.log('cldata : '+ clarifaiData)
      var responseObject = {imageURL: imageURL, data: clarifaiData }
      // console.log('rObj : '+responseObject)
      res.send((responseObject));
  });

  app.get('/classify', function(req, res) {
    res.json((store));
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to install globally. After installing there would be a node_modules directory at the same location that includes the clarifai package as well as any other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you're missing a semicolon when you make an instance of Clarifai at...

```
var ClarifaiInstance = new Clarifai.App(
  keys.access_key,
  keys.secret_key
)
```

...which may contribute to your issue.

Check to see that Clarifai is listed in your `package.json` dependencies.  If not, try running a `npm install clarifai --save` as the --save option instructs npm to add the package to your list of dependencies automatically.

Also, sometimes running a simple `npm install` solves any dependency or weird node.js problems that may be happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved your Clarifai dependencies from the front end to the backend, you will need to run `npm install clarifai` within your api / backend files. Once you've done this, check your package.json file to make sure clarifai is listed among your dependencies.